# Why does Random Forest using SAP PAL predict the same value for every input?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, sap, random-forest, decision-tree

I am using SAP Predictive Analytics Library to predict a certain variable. For this, I am using Random Decision Tree( also known as Random Fores) algorithm. I have 24 features and 25k rows. I am using the following parameters to train the model.

```
INSERT INTO #PAL_PARAMETER_TBL VALUES ('HAS_ID', 1, null, null);
INSERT INTO #PAL_PARAMETER_TBL VALUES ('TREES_NUM', 100, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO #PAL_PARAMETER_TBL VALUES ('TRY_NUM', 3, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO #PAL_PARAMETER_TBL VALUES ('MAX_DEPTH ', 6, null, NULL);
INSERT INTO #PAL_PARAMETER_TBL VALUES ('SEED', 0, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO #PAL_PARAMETER_TBL VALUES ('SPLIT_THRESHOLD', NULL, 1e-5, NULL);
INSERT INTO #PAL_PARAMETER_TBL VALUES ('CALCULATE_OOB', 1, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO #PAL_PARAMETER_TBL VALUES ('NODE_SIZE', 500, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO #PAL_PARAMETER_TBL VALUES ('THREAD_RATIO', NULL, 1.0, NULL);
```

The following is the output that I get-

[image: Predicted output]

The left column is the predicted output and the right column is the confidence.
The actual value is supposed to be as follows-

[image: Actual value]

In my training set, I have values (for the Dependent variable) ranging from 1.7 to 4. So, my question is why is the model behaving in this manner ? Also I have noticed that using the same dataset for Decision Tree algorithm I get close enough values to the actual output. Since Random forest is based on Decision tree, it should output more accurate values !

Please help.

REFERENCE - [SAP PAL Reference guide](https://help.sap.com/doc/86fb8d26952748debc8d08db756e6c1f/2.0.03/en-US/SAP_HANA_Predictive_Analysis_Library_PAL_en.pdf)

Comment: You may have used wrong parameters, have you tried running it without any additional parameters (default settings)?

Comment: @user2974951 Yes I have tried with the default parameters. It did not work